# Bootstrap datetimepicker not opening separately

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I select and choose first date input, second date input will open calendar on same position as first one. It looks like both dates are selected from one calendar. How to reach that calendars would open on each date input separately?

Current:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

HTML:

```
<form id="filter"> 
  <table class="vms">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', maxDate: $.now(), stepping: 5})
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({ format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', maxDate: $.now(), stepping: 5})
```

Datetimepicker that I'm using:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Which Bootstrap verison are you using?

Comment: Are your inputs in different containers or are they just displayed one underneath the other like in your question?

Comment: @chade_ Bootstrap 3

Comment: @Sorix No, they are in the same container.

Comment: Try placing them in two different parents and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Sorix
how would you do this?

Comment: See my answer below. It is the same thing as the Linked Pickers in the doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a working example it may be helpful to you

```js
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is insired by Linked Pickers in the [doc](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)